# Updating Response Structure of REST APIs

Tags: json, rest, jsonpath

This question is more on seeking the right approach for an inherent programming challenge of backward compatibility. I am trying to understand if this violates the backward compatibility of an existing REST API.

**If you think that this is not the right place, please mention in the comment the right forum where I can ask this question.**

I have a REST API which returns the following response:

```
[
   {
      "name":"accountID",
      "value":500
   },
   {
      "name":"accountType",
      "value":"PREMIUM"
   },
   {
      "name":"supportType",
      "value":"Phone"
   }    
]
```

Now due to some recent updates I have to send additional information in the API and the updated response is below:

```
[
   {
      "name":"accountID",
      "value":500,
      "encrypted":false
   },
   {
      "name":"accountType",
      "value":"PREMIUM",
      "encrypted":true
   },
   {
      "name":"supportType",
      "value":"Phone",
      "encrypted":false
   }    
]
```

Please help me in understanding if I am breaking any backward compatibility. As far as my understanding goes, backward compatibility will be broken only if I remove something from the existing JSON response and not by adding extra in JSON.

As most of the JSON libraries provide features to ignore on unrecognized properties.

Even if we navigate through the object one node at a time using jsonpath, it should be ok if someone doesn't understand the new property.